My button's color seems transparent in QtDesigner but why?
I'm using QTDesigner 5.15.8 and trying to color buttons.

I have inserted one button and frame on my mainwindow.
Here is the stylesheet code of mainwindow
QPushButton{
background-color: red;
}
QFrame{
background-color: red;
}

They are same but as you see they look different.
I couldnt find why it happened but it happens even if I created a new project...

Setting the background color only is similar to setting the palette: the style still uses the given color as reference, if by default it uses gradients (common to most styles), then you'll still get gradients. The only option you have is to also set the borders, but that means that you should also add, at the very least, a rule for the "inset" pressed state too.

I found the solution, it is border...

Warning: If you only set a background-color on a QPushButton, the background may not appear unless you set the border property to some value. This is because, by default, the QPushButton draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color. For example,
QPushButton { background-color: red; border: none; }
See Customizing QPushButton for an example.

